# Regular Expressions for whitespaces, digits and commas

Tags: javascript, regex

I need help with a regular expression to allow only numbers, commas, and whitespaces in JavaScript. 
For example :

"123456,78889,871253,85879"        valid
",12002, 102878,11000"       &nbsp           valid
"77,1293,abc"                                   not valid (Due to the abc)

So far I have got :

```
var regex = new RegExp("[^0-9]|[^\,]|[^\s]");
if (regex.exec(myValue) === null) {
     // value is valid
}
```

Comment: no need to alternate those 3 types. `[^0-9\,\s]` is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
var regex = /^[0-9\,\s]+$/;
```

[Demo](http://regexr.com?358lc)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJP3e/)

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[0-9,\s]*$/.test("1234565, 123545, abc");
```

this returns false

Comment: You should replace the space by `\s` that contains all "white characters"

Comment: regex.exec("1234565, 123545, abc") was returning null, but thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this one? /^[0-9, ]*$/
it should be enough

http://www.debuggex.com/r/s_4F8WHNl0nyLs0L